# how to open multiple windows in selenium at the same time. python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

am trying to open multiple windows  of the same URL using selenium,
I used a for loop to open the multiple windows:

```
for i in range(x):
    driver = web driver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
    driver.get('testing')
```

but the problem is that the for loop wait until each element to open and load and when it finish automating the website and then it opens the next window. I want all of the windows open simultaneously and execute simultaneously to shorten the time needed, thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure why it was considered as duplicated. The answer here is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Selenium 4 currently in Alpha only https://pypi.org/project/selenium/4.0.0.a7/

It provides the following for opening new windows and tabs:

```
# Opens a new tab and switches to new tab
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')

# Opens a new window and switches to new window
driver.switch_to.new_window('window')
```